Stack of smooth fiber bundles with fiber $F$
I'd like to premise that while I know the definition of (differentiable) stack, I'm not really into the language of schemes so my understanding of what is a moduli stack is pretty concrete and intuitive.
I denote $\textbf{Man}$ the category of smooth manifolds with smooth maps.
Let $F$ be a smooth manifold, and let $\mathbf{FB}_F$ be the category of smooth fiber bundles with fiber $F$ (the morphisms are only the pullback morphisms). We can define the functor:
$$\mathbf{FB}_F\to \mathbf{Man}$$
that associates to a smooth $F$-fiber bundle $\pi:E\to B$ the base $B$, and to a pullback morphism $f:E_1\to E_2$, its base $\underline{f}:B_1\to B_2$. It seems to me that this defines a stack (in the sense of a category fibered in groupoids with good gluing properties).
Is this a differentiable stack for some manifold $F$? I think this should be the moduli stack of the full subcategory of $\textbf{Man}$ whom objects are the manifolds diffeomorphic to $F$.
I tried finding some Lie group(oid) to present this stack. The first candidate that came to my mind was the diffeomorphism group of the fiber $F$, but it's simply too big.

What's wrong with an infinite-dimensional Lie groupoid?

@DavidRoberts Let $\mathbf{B}\text{Diffeo}(F)$ be the category of $\text{Diffeo}(F)$-principal bundles.  If $\text{Diffeo}(F)$ presents the moduli stack, then there is a stack equivalence $\mathbf{FB}_F\to \mathbf{B}\text{Diffeo}(F)$. How is this equivalence constructed?

I will deal with the case that $F$ is compact. Your definition of the stack of fibre bundles permits us to consider just the functor between groupoids that are the single fibres over a fixed manifold $X$ (where the morphisms are isomorphisms between bundles covering the identity map). To build a principal $\mathrm{Diffeo}(F)$-bundle on $X$ from a fibre bundle with fibre $F$, it suffices, since we are working with stacks, to build it locally. Even better, it is possible by local compactness of $X$ to work over a precompact (open) ball and its closure in some chart.

This means if we can just consider a fibre bundle $P$ with fibre $F$ on the closed unit ball $B$. It is clearly trivialisable, and we consider the space of isomorphisms $B\times F \to P$ over the base. $P$ is compact, and so is $B\times F$, and so I'm pretty sure this carves out a Fréchet manifold (using the compactness of $B$) from the space of all diffeomorphisms between the two total spaces of the bundles. The diffeomorphism group of $F$ acts on this by precomposition, freely and transitively. Thus you can make a trivial principal bundle on $B$ with this fibre.

And then you see what happens on restriction to a smaller ball (you can choose a good cover of $X$, there might be some fiddliness about double-checking/using continuous extension to the boundary of the open ball, I hope this is not too awful - it boils down to using the fact all derivatives are uniformly continuous, hence bounded), and also when you have a given isomorphism of one bundle on a ball with another bundle on the same ball, you get an equivariant diffeomorphism of these $\mathrm{Diffeo}(F)$-manifolds. And thus you can build a principal bundle.

This is the hard direction. The other direction is easier: take a principal $\mathrm{Diffeo}(F)$-bundle and form the associated bundle with given fibre $F$. This doesn't need any fiddling around, and also proving this is the object component of a functor is much easier. You really only need all the above tech to ensure this easier functor is actually essentially surjective.

Thank you very much! :)

Another way to view it is that you only need the functor $\underline{\ast} \to \mathbf{B}\mathrm{Diffeo}(F) \to \mathbf{FB}_F$ to be an epimorphism of stacks, and such that the (2-cateogrical) pullback of this along itself is $\mathrm{Diffeo}(F)$. Essential surjectivity follows I think from the fact there is up to iso only one trivial fibre bundle with fibre $F$, and all fibre bundles are locally trivial. The other fact has to do with automorphisms of the trivial fibre bundle, which I think you can check directly should be representable by  $\mathrm{Diffeo}(F)$.
